# Reverse Poll Votes

Tags: discussion, support, polling

I think this should be allowed, but it currently is not. Opinions?

I understand the ballot sense that once you submit your vote it wouldn't be retractable, I just realized after thinking about it for a bit that I would like to change my vote.

Perhaps the same system? Votes get locked in after 30 minutes?

Comment: Poll? What poll?

Comment: @Daniel This was a poll from back in August regarding the [merge of two Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-be-merged-vote/). The poll has [since been resolved](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/fork-it/), and there are no other polls available.

Comment: What is a "reverse poll vote"? A question containing the word "Yes" where people list the feature requests they like in answers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with being able to reverse a poll vote.

If you think you're going to probably change your vote within the next 30 minutes, then you really haven't decided your place yet and shouldn't be casting a vote. There is no rush to make your vote as soon as you can, so take the time to evaluate your stance first. Once you find your choice to be concrete, that's when you vote.

Comment: But what's the harm in allowing the vote to be changed? You seem to prefer sacrificing the accuracy of the poll to teach a lesson to the users who voted impulsively.

Comment: @Kop In a general scenario, I wouldn't expect even 1% of the total stats to account for votes that people would have liked to reverse immediately after casting it. Adding this ability would actually encourage people to rush their vote, thinking "If I change my mind, I can always swap it out later". I would rather we don't encourage this indecisive mindset.

Comment: What if someone reads discussions about merging and decides to reverse their initial vote? I assumed it was possible to change your vote until this [came up](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66/retract-change-poll-vote) and I tried it; why does the other button even exist if it's just going to give you an error when you click it?

Comment: @Michael I can't vote so I don't know what the results look like after you have voted. I expected that the button would be removed.

Comment: @Michael But to talk about reversing the initial vote, this would require extending a much larger timespan, perhaps days. One should not be preparing to encounter discussion that results in reversing a decision within minutes or hours of casting the vote. And when you reach days of leeway, it questions the concept of solidifying the vote at all - why leave it at only X days and expect people to only reverse within that period? At which point, the numbers recorded by previous votes are even more meaningless than they already are. And if the early votes are meaningless - why have them early?